# want to remove action name from url CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, url-rewriting, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am working on a Cakephp 2.x.. i want to remove the action or controller name from url ... for example i am facing a problem is like that

i have a function  name **index** on my **Messages** controller in which all the mobile numbers are displaying

the url is

```
  www.myweb.com/Messages
```

now in my controller there is a second function whose name is **messages** in which i am getting the messages against the mobile number

so now my url becomes after clicking the number is

```
    www.myweb.com/Messages/messages/823214
```

now i want to remove the action name messages because it looks weired... 
want to have a url like this

```
       www.myweb.com/Messages/823214
```

Comment: do you [look at the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) before asking questions =)? Have you tried anything?

Comment: yup i have tried.. but nothing worked

Comment: Router::connect(
    '/messages/'
    array('controller' => 'messages', 'action' => 'messages')));

Answer (score 1):

When connecting routes using Route elements you may want to have routed elements be passed arguments instead. By using the 3rd argument of [Router::connect()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#routes-configuration) you can define which route elements should also be made available as passed arguments:

```
// SomeController.php

public function messages($phoneNumber = null) {
    // some code here...
}

// routes.php
Router::connect(
    '/messages/:id', // E.g. /messages/number
    array('controller' => 'messages', 'action' => 'messages'),
    array(
        // order matters since this will simply map ":id" 
        'id' => '[0-9]+'
    )
);
```

and you can also refer link above given by me, hope it will work for you.

let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: if you go throw the document link with detail, that would be really helpful to solve your issue. :)

Comment: +1 that'll only work though by changing how urls are generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cake-PHP's Routing Features.  Check out [this page](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/development/routing.html).

Answer (score 0):

### REST Routing

The example in the question looks similar to [REST routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html), a built in feature which would map:

```
GET    /recipes/123    RecipesController::view(123)
```

To enable rest routing just use `Router::mapResources('controllername');`

### Individual route

If you want only to write a route for the one case in the question
it's necessary to use a star route:

```
Router::connect('/messages/*', 
    array(
        'controller' => 'messages',
        'action' => 'messages'
    )
);
```

Usage:

```
echo Router::url(array(
    'controller' => 'messages',
    'action' => 'messages',
    823214
));
// /messages/823214
```

**This has drawbacks** because it's not possible with this kind of route to validate what comes after `/messages/`. To avoid that requires using route parameters.

```
Router::connect('/messages/:id',
    array(
        'controller' => 'messages',
        'action' => 'messages'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '\d+',
    )
);
```

Usage:

```
echo Router::url(array(
    'controller' => 'messages',
    'action' => 'messages',
    'id' => 823214 // <- different usage
));
// /messages/823214
```

Comment: as far as I understand your answer you are saying that I use router connect which obviously I write in the routes.php class ... and the second u have said that use Router::url ? you mean what ? should I replace this <?php echo  $this->Html->link($contact['Contact']['name'], array('action' => 'messages', $contact['Message']['mobileNo'])); ?></td>
?   to Router::url

Comment: All routes are defined using the route definitions in routes.php (it is not a class). The two options in the answer are rest routes or defining an individual route. Router::url is where all urls come from - i.e. [all helpers use it](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/View/Helper.php#L253) to get urls; I'm not suggesting anything changes in how urls are generated, your code (whatever it is) is already using it.

Answer (score 0):

in  config/routes.php

```
$routes->connect('/NAME-YOU-WANT/:id',
        ['controller' => 'CONTROLLER-NAME','action'=>'ACTIOn-NAME'])->setPass(['id'])->setPatterns(['id' => '[0-9]+']
    );
```