# Routing with JS on Paginator-Page

Tags: jquery, cakephp, routes

I think I have a general routing problem.

Look what i got. I have a Page with a Paginator on it. at the time I enter the page I have an url like that "host/OnlineBanking/session_details/session_id:xxxxxx".

If I use the paginator I got something like that "host/OnlineBanking/session_details/session_id:xxxxxx/page:2"

Still easy to understand.

But the problem is the JS I use here. I got a button which got an on-click-event behind.

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',                               
                url: "../get_backend_requests",                 
                data: "request_id="+request_id,                 
                dataType: "html",
                success :function(html){                        
                    element.append(html);       
                }             
            });
```

So the Problem is if i define the URL like I does up there I work perfect with the first URL I posted first. But the second URL with the page-parameter renders the full Layout without those data I want to have. In the action I call from the JS I have the the autoRender value set to false so there cant be the problem.
I used Firebug to figure out what happen and the problem is that the JS just append the action to call on the previous one. So the URL looks like that "OnlineBanking/session_details/get_backend_requests". 
So I can fix the problem by using this "url: "../../get_backend_requests" in the ajax but then the URL without the /page:2 ain't work no more. because he try to use and action as an Controller.

Can anybody give me a hint to solve this problem.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

It is better to have declare a constant in bootstrap.php

```
define('HTTP_HOST', "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/');
define('SITE_URL', HTTP_HOST.'your_project_dir_name_if_any/');
```

And use it like following:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',                               
            url: "<?php echo SITE_URL.'controller_name/get_backend_requests';?>",                 
            data: "request_id="+request_id,                 
            dataType: "html",
            success :function(html){                        
                element.append(html);       
            }             
        });
```

Comment: so, there is no way to change the URL display behavior? So if I call the get_backend_requests-Action out of the JS that the parameter from the pager for example is ignored and cutted?

Comment: I mean that isn't normal that Get-parameters display like that /page:5 for example. I thought the correct why would be for example Controller/action?param1=help&param2=me&param3=out.

Comment: This link might help you to change the URL action: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506287/want-to-remove-action-name-from-url-cakephp